# Data not retrieved in text-box where I used Date picker

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello Stack Overflow Team,
When click to edit link for edit customer details form  displayed. 
in this form all exist data displayed except datepicker data not displayed.
all data comping from the Web API.

EditUser.component.html

```
 <mat-form-field class="demo-full-width">
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" matTooltip="Enter Date Of Birth"
                placeholder="Choose Date Of Birth" formControlName="DataOfBirth">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

EditUser.component.ts

```
   this.service.getRegistrationDetails(this.registrationId).subscribe(data => {
  this.updateUserForm.controls['First_Name'].setValue(data.FirstName);
  const dateOfBirth = this.datePipe.transform(data.DataOfBirth.toString(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');});
```

Service.ts

```
getRegistrationDetails(registrationId: string): Observable<Register> {
// debugger;
return this.http.get<Register>(this.url + '/GetRegistration/' + registrationId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code in your EditUser typescript file, you aren't setting the value of your date into your FormControl. You put the value of the date into a const variable named `dateOfBirth` but don't do anything with it afterwards. I'm guessing you will need something like this:

```
this.updateUserForm.controls['DataOfBirth'].setValue(dateOfBirth);
```

After you store the value in your const.

Edit: After looking at it again it's also possible that you are sending the incorrect date format to the control. By default I believe that the Angular DatePicker works with native Javascript Date objects.

I don't know what the data type of your results are coming from the `getRegistrationDetails()` function. But if the birth date is a string you can convert it to a Date object as below. If it's already a Date object, just skip the first line converting it to a Date and set it directly into the form control.

```
this.service.getRegistrationDetails(this.registrationId).subscribe(data => {
  const dateOfBirth = new Date(data.DataOfBirth);
  this.updateUserForm.setValue({
    'First_Name': data.FirstName,
    'DataOfBirth': dateOfBirth
  });
});
```

Comment: After setting the value of data into  datepicker control like this in .TS file ` const dateOfBirth = this.datePipe.transform(data.DataOfBirth.toString(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');});this.updateUserForm.controls['DataOfBirth'].setValue(dateOfBirth);` afterwards ,i also did get data in datepicker control.

Comment: So you're saying that it worked with that change? If so you can mark this as the answer, otherwise if you have other questions let me know!

Comment: After changes of this, it also not working , data is not coming into datepicker control.